# Excel multiple FIND formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am no expert with excel so any help is appreciated!

I am trying to make one cell do multiple searches within another.

I know that to search one cell for a specific word you would use 
=FIND(Blue,C2)

But I need to find multiple different words in one cell. Heres an example of what im trying to do:

[image: heres an example of what im trying to do]

I need to show all the allergens in the ingredients cell eg peanuts, gluten, milk, sesame seeds etc

How do I get the result to list all the allergens?

I know that I can do a single find function in separate cells and then concatenate them, but there must be a more simple way?

Thanks

Comment: are you just looking to confirm the presence of multiple words or do you need to know where they appear in the string?

Comment: What form of search result do you expect to get? Assuming that more that 1 word of search for list can be found...

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by find different words in one cell.  Please provide some example cells and what you want the result to be.  This could refer to finding the presence or count of any, each, or all, and then how and where do you express the result?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what FIND does - this would return a number rather than the word. I assume what you want the formula to do is in return the words that match

Comment: i need it to return as a word, i thought if you use " it would define the word?

Comment: Your question is still ambiguous.  Please add: 1. What the result of the example should look like.  2. What form the target words are in (hard code a fixed collection of words in the formula vs. reference a fixed list vs. reference a dynamic list).  3. Are you interested in any match or every match?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1386644/multiple-search-formula-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest Two possible methods. **1st is Formula** and **2nd is MACRO.***

**Method 1:**

[image]

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(SEARCH(B1,A1)>0,SEARCH(C1,A1)>0,SEARCH(D1,A1)>0,SEARCH(E1,A1)>0),"Found",""),"Nfound")
```

**Note:**

- Write this Formula in cell `G1` and drag it Down.
- You can extend the Formula, if more Text/Words to be searched.

**Method 2:**

[image]

- At the Active Sheet press `Alt+F11` to open `VB Editor`.
- **Copy & Paste** below show code as *Standard Module*.
- Select the Range `A1:A3`, where you want to search Text/Words to **highlight**.
- **RUN** the Macro.
- Enter Words in **INPUT BOX**, separated by Comma and press **OK**

*Macro will Bold Face the words been found in Range `A1:A3`.*

```
Sub MultiFindNBoldFace()

Dim strSearch As String
Dim arySearch As Variant
Dim searchRng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Long, ii As Long


Set searchRng = Application.Selection
strSearch = InputBox("Please enter the text to make bold as a comma delimited list (Abc,Xyz) - No spaces:", "Bold Text")
If strSearch = "" Then Exit Sub
arySearch = Split(strSearch, ",")
For Each cel In searchRng

With cel

.Font.Bold = False
For ii = LBound(arySearch) To UBound(arySearch)

i = InStr(cel.Value, arySearch(ii))
If i > 0 Then

.Characters(i, Len(arySearch(ii))).Font.Bold = True
End If
Next ii
End With
Next cel

End Sub
```

*You can adjust cell references in the Formula as well as in the Macro also.*