# Multiple Search Formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, search, find, concatenation

I am trying to find a formula which will search one cell for specific words.

I would like the outcome of the formula to be words I have selected.

The example of this I have is if one cell shows the list of ingredients, and the other cell shows a list of allergens. I need the formula to search the list of ingredients and choose the allergens.

[image]

I know that I could use the find function so that it came back with one result and then concatenate the results but there must be a more simple way!

Thanks

Comment: nope I doubt there is a more simple way, use CONCATENATE MID & FIND, it should be fairly simple to achieve

Comment: Can you explain how you would do it please?

Comment: Yeah sure, edit your question to show exactly what is in Cell C3, and what exactly you want to see in C6, and I will show you how I would go about doing it

Comment: don't use image, just type it out please

Comment: In Cell C3: Oats, rice syrup,cacao nibs, cashew nuts, pea protein crisps, sunflower seeds, coconut oil, cacao powder, matcha green tea, sea salt, almond oil

Comment: In Cell C6 It needs to have the allegens which would be oats, nuts, sunflower seeds, almond

Answer (score 3):

If you have Office 365 Excel which introduced TEXTJOIN, You can use it in an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND( {"GLUTEN","PEANUTS"},C3)),{"GLUTEN","PEANUTS"},""))
```

Being an Array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

This will iterate the two names and test the string with Find.  If found then Find returnd a number if not an error.  We find where it returns a number and then the second array will return the correct value to the TEXT JOIN

[image]

---

But a better practice would be to create a table with the allergens listed:

[image]

Then you can refer to that list in the TEXTJOIN formula instead of maintaining it in the formula itself:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH( ALLERGEN[ALLERGENS],C3)),ALLERGEN[ALLERGENS],""))
```

Still an array formula, and I switched to SEARCH to deal with the difference of capitalization.

[image]

Now, as new allergens are needed the they can be added to the list without the need to update the formula.

Comment: I have office for Mac 2016, will this change what to input?

Comment: @Imi then you probably do not have TEXTJOIN.  It available only with Office 365 Excel and later.

Comment: do you have an alternative answer for excel 2016?

Comment: No, you will need to do what @peterH answered.  There is no quick formula fix in your edition.

Comment: ’ve been playing with this formula because I couldn’t get the original syntax to work and it’s nearly doing what I would like. Please can you help me make it case insensitive?

Here is the data and my current formula:

Comment: {=TEXTJOIN(,",",,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table1[[#All],[Column1]],C3)),Table1[[#All],[Column1]],""))}

Answer (score 2):

In Cell C6 you can use the below formula,

```
=MID(C3,FIND("Gluten",C3),LEN("Gluten"))&", "&MID(C3,FIND("Peanuts",C3),LEN("Peanuts"))
```

you can add more allergens to serch for by adding the below onto the end of the formula:

```
&", "&MID(C3,FIND("Another Allergen",C3),LEN("Another Allergen"))
```

And repeat as needed.

You can also error proof this for when you list an allergen which may not be in the ingredients:

```
=IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND("Gluten",C3),LEN("Gluten")),"")&", "&IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND("Peanuts",C3),LEN("Peanuts")),"")&", "&IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND("Another Allergen",C3),LEN("Another Allergen")),"")
```

Because this uses FIND the search pattern is case sensitive, you may want to consider swapping there for the SEARCH function which still takes the same 2 arguments in the same order.

Comment: It has come back with 'Not enough arguments were entered for this function.'

Comment: will the error proof work if the ingredients is in the list of allergens?